# Why does the slide of my javascript carousel not reset?

Tags: javascript, html, timer, carousel, slide

I have a carousel that goes through the slides every 4 seconds if the user doesn't click on anything. However, the problem I am getting is that if, for example, the user clicks on a slide after 1 second, and then the next one after 2 seconds, the following slides don't appear 4 seconds later. The js code is below:

```
var arr = [];
arr[0]= new Image();
arr[0].src = "1.jpg";
arr[1]= new Image();
arr[1].src = "2.jpg";
arr[2]= new Image();
arr[2].src = "3.jpg";

titleArray = new Array();
titleArray[0] = "first";
titleArray[1] = "second";
titleArray[2] = "third";

var i=0;

function slide(){
document.getElementById("img1").src= arr[i].src;
document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = titleArray[i];
    i++;
    if(i==arr.length){
        i=0;
    }
setTimeout(function(){ slide(); },4000);
}
```

The html is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>Carousel</title>

 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300,700'     rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body onLoad="slide();">

<div class="image">
  <img src="1.jpg" width="510" height="390" id="img1">
  <a href="JavaScript:slide(this)">  
<img src="carousel-label-box.png"    id="img2" width="310" height="190"> 
  </a>
  <h1 id="title">first</h1>

 </div>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean when the user clicks on the images the slide will change before the intended 4 seconds?

From what I see you should call clearTimeout() to interrupt it and then set it again when the user clicks on the images instead of simply calling slide.

**EDIT:** Forgot to mention you should still call slide() function when the user clicks it.

Comment: I just noticed you called setTimeout inside the function slide. This makes it so whenever the user clicks on the image, another Timeout for your slide() function is called in between the original one. You should call setTimeout outside of your function.
Let me know if it works.